# Adding a settings file to a front-end web application in an async manner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, single-page-application

I'm currently trying to resolve some with an SPA being built with a lot of custom components, borrowing a lot from all over the place.

The current challenge I have is initializing some settings (Endpoint URLs and the sort) with a settings file to be set on a per-deployment basis. It's Javascript, so it makes sense to relegate this to a JSON file. However, a lot of the logic is still written in this strongly-defined OO methodology, and I am trying to determine the best method to load this settings file within the async methodology.

Looking at other topics on Stack Overflow, the jQuery getJSON method is a viable option. But I am not clear if it is still based on synchronous calls. Furthermore, If there is an async option, I want to be sure that the value is loaded before firing any additional logic in the application (instead of having it initialize nothing at the constructor).

Is my assumption correct? Is getJSON the best approach here? Code is listed below.

```
var settings = $.getJSON("conf.json");
var SearchObject = new Search(settings);
// Remainder is just a bunch of bind() and on() calls
```

Answer (score 0):

$.getJSON is just a shortcut for more detailed $.ajax call where you can adjust much more parameters, like callback if you need. And no, $.getJSON same as $.ajax

> Perform an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

The getJSON jquery function is async by default.

```
$.getJSON({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR ){}
});
```

It is the same as:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR ){}
});
```

But, with the ajax function you can set async to false if you want.
eg.

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  async: false,
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR ){}
});
```

Comment: I had heard conflicting statements about this as of jQuery 1.10.x, where async: false is deprecated.

Comment: @CameronKilgore, check API page - "async: ... As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; "